Principal curvature is intrinsic when $n>2$ and can be solved from curvatrue operator?
It's in general believed that principal curvature is extrinsic. But I found following wield problem:
Let $S$ be a $n$-hypersurface in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, then the principal curvature $k_i$ are eigenvalues of $II(X,Y)=-g(SX,Y)$ with $S=\nabla n$ the shape operaor, now we know $R(X,Y,Z,W)=II(X\wedge Y,Z\wedge W)$, as a corollary, if $E_j$ are eigenvectors of $II$ (or $S$), then $E_i\wedge E_j$ are eigenvectors of curvature operator with eigenvalue $k_ik_j$(see for example this post). This leads to the fact that $\{k_ik_j\}$ is intrinsic, as a corollary Gaussian curvature or even degree coefficients of characteristic polynomial of $S$ must be intrinsic up to a sign(see for example  references here).
(1)If $n\geq 3$, so $n(n-1)/2\geq n$, then it seems that we can actually solve the princpal curvatures from eigenvalues of curvature operator if at least $n$ of then is nonzero?
(2)This in particular implies if the curvature is nondegenerate, then principal curvatures and principal subspaces are intrinsicly defined. Is is true that in general the eigenvectors of curvature operator are decomposable bivectors $E_i\wedge E_j$ with $E_j$ some orthonormal basis?
(3)Does this give us some information or restrictions on manifolds that can be locally isometriclly embdeded in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$(I believe this cannot be done in general)?

See the paper by Berger-Bryant-Griffiths I posted in a comment to your other question.
